# How do I get the formatted text as in direct passing a string?

Tags: command-line, bash

direct passing a string with `$` to `echo`

```
$ echo $'#include <iostream>\nint main() {\n  std::cout << \"Hello World!\" << std::endl;\n}'
```

expands the embedded ANSI escape sequences

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

I assigned the string to a variable

```
codeStr='#include <iostream>\nint main() {\n  std::cout << \"Hello World!\" << std::endl;\n}'
```

and then echo the variable

```
echo $codeStr
```

I got the raw string rather than a formatted text.

How do I get the formatted text as in direct passing a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`-e`** switch to [`enable interpretation of backslash escapes`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo).

```
$ codeStr='#include <iostream>\nint main() {\n  std::cout << \"Hello World!\" << std::endl;\n}'
$ echo -e $codeStr 
#include <iostream>
int main() {
 std::cout << \"Hello World!\" << std::endl;
}
```

Addressing @steeldriver comment, `printf` also works (and it interpret the sequence correctly).

```
$ codeStr='#include <iostream>\nint main() {\n  std::cout << \"Hello World!\" << std::endl;\n}'
$ printf "$codeStr"
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: ... note that whereas `$'...'` treats `\"` as an escape sequence, the bash shell's builtin `echo -e` doesn't (hence the output here is actually different from the OP's). See also [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)